# Swift: Putting Tab bar in front of the view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've been struggling with my tabbar being hidden after I invoke segue to get back to one of the previous viewcontrollers.

I read that after a segue, the view covers the tabbar. Is there a way to put the tab bar on top of the view so that it is visibile?

I tried everything else to make the tab bar appear after the segue and it just doesn't work..

Comment: Are you segue from A to B, then use another segue to go back from B to A?

Comment: I have 3 view controllers( A, B and C). A and B are on tab bar - A generates data from API and shows it on the View controller C. C adds it to the tableview on B that was part of the tab bar. After using the add segue, the tab bar does not show anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the `UITabBar` should be hidden for any `UIViewController` you are going to be displaying just check the property in the attributes inspector as show below, the "Hide bottom bar on push" check box.  For any `UIViewController` that doesn't have this property checked, as soon as it appears, the `UITabBar` will show.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it was unchecked. I also tried Embedding a navigation controller etc. I'm almost about to create another view controller with the same data to solve this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating another instance of B that doesnt embedded in tabbar when you call the segue

Assume you embedded A and C in nav controller and B is 2nd vc in tabbar, what you need to do is:

1.Get the vc B with `self.tabBarController?.viewControllers[1] as! B` and assign its data there

2.Change the tab with `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`

If C is modal segue from A, just use delegate/unwind back to A and do the above